# How to access a class's function inside a another class's function's function

Tags: javascript, function, class

I am creating a phaser3 game, and for that I want to create media queries to make a mobile responsive game.  I am using a function which acts as the media query.  The problem is that my game is separated through classes, and inside of a function of a class, I have to access other class functions inside of the media query function that is inside a class function.  Here is the code:

```
class MenuScene extends BaseScene {

  // Other code

  create() {
    // Other code

    function mediaQuery(x) { 
      if (x.matches) {
        this.createMenu2(gameState.menu, this.setupMenuEvents().bind(this));
      } else {
        this.createMenu(gameState.menu, this.setupMenuEvents().bind(this));
      }
    }
    let x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 846px)");
    mediaQuery(x);
    x.addEventListener("change", mediaQuery);
  }
}
```

The **createMenu** functions are for creating the game menu.  When I look in the console, it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMenu' of undefined
```

Please tell me how I can access the function createMenu, which is in another class.  Thank you!

**Update 1**: Here is the createMenu in the BaseScene:

```
createMenu(menu, setupMenuEvents) {

  let lastMenuPositionY = 0;

  menu.forEach(menuItem => {
    const menuPosition = [this.screenCenter[0], this.screenCenter[1] + lastMenuPositionY];
    menuItem.textGO = this.add.text(...menuPosition, menuItem.text, this.fontOptions).setOrigin(0.5, 1);
    lastMenuPositionY += this.lineHeight;
    setupMenuEvents(menuItem);
  });
};
```

Thank you again!

Comment: I will add the functions from BaseScene.

Comment: After having formatted the above code it is much more easy to spot the probable source of failure. Since `mediaQuery` gets assigned as event handler its `this` context is not anymore a `MenuScene` instance but the `MediaQueryList` type which got assigned to `x` and does now listen to a `change` event. Thus one possible solution was to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the handler's context as follows ... `x.addEventListener("change", mediaQuery.bind(this));`

Comment: It still has the un caught type error.  I will edit my post to include the BaseScene.

Comment: Since `mediaQuery` does not just need the correct context but also the right argument (`x`) one of cause needs to change the binding to ... `x.addEventListener("change", mediaQuery.bind(this, x));` ... and the first call has to change from `mediaQuery(x);` to `mediaQuery.call(this, x);`. Please read up yourself on [*binding*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#syntax) and *context*.

Comment: I could not get this to work, but I did find a work around.  Thank you for your time!